# Hebrew date format with momentjs

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, hebrew

I changed locale to 'he' and use this format:

```
moment().format('D MMM')
```

it formated like this: **3 אפר׳** but I want to show date with this symbol **'ב'** which means (3 in Apr) like this: **3 באפר׳**

How can I make this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What was the input date?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it doesn't matter, I want format any date like this

Comment: Surely the input date matters? If you give 12th Dec, why would it give 3rd July?

Comment: @evolutionxbox for this particular case 3 Apr. But it doesn't matter because the question is about format

Comment: I think the point was: most of us here can't read Hebrew and we have no idea what that additional character represents, therefore your initial example of  29 אפר׳ vs  3 באפר׳ was confusing at best.

Comment: @deceze yeah I got it and have already corrected it

Comment: Worth pointing out that [moment.js is now deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: @Liam ...but only for reasons that don't have anything to do with the functionality it provides.

Comment: Well, there is the fact that it's [pretty much unnecessary in modern JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72025727/542251)

Answer (score 2):

The format string can contain other characters than just date part placeholders, you can do it directly:

```js
moment.locale('he');

console.log(moment('2022-04-03').format('D בMMM'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/locale/he.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without moment at all. The [`Intl` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) does this without any additional libraries in modern JS. If you want to [support IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#browser_compatibility) then you might need moment, if not, I'd recommend using `Intl` over moment. Not least of which, [because moment is deprecated](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

```js
const intl = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('he', {month: "short", day:"numeric"});
console.log(intl.format(new Date('2022-04-03')));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - how would this look if the question were the other way around (*"I don't want the ב"*)? Is there a way to specify a custom format?

Comment: Not really, the whole point of the intl object is the use the ISO standardisation. If you think about it there is no such thing as a "custom date". Dates have very well defined syntax. The whole point of this kind of thing is to get away from everyone inventing their own way of doing internationalisation.

Comment: That's ... a very optimistic take. :) Dates are supposed to look like the stakeholders of the application you're writing want them to look like, there is no such thing as a fixed set of generally agreed upon formats that cover every need. Date formatting preferences are wild, there can only be "largest common denominators". As long as `Intl`'s defaults work, it's fine. As soon as they don't, something more flexible still has its merits.

Comment: Don't disagree, if you want to ignore generally agreed formats that's up to you and yes you can then use a library if you want. That's probably fine for organisations working in one (or a few) culture(s). But there is no practical way to define a custom date format for every culture in the world. That's why there are standards

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there is a built in method for that in moment.js, but you can use regex:

`moment().format('D MMM').replace(/\d+? /, '$&ב')`